# How to skip 2 iteration in java loop

Tags: java

I have a loop where single iteration is skipped using `continue`:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            if(i==2){
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Output would be `0 1 3 4`

Based on my criteria above like i==2, I want to get output `0 1 4`.
Meaning I want to skip 2 iterations. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(i==2){
        i++
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Increment i by one inside the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would stay away from skipping the loop for certain counters. What do you gain from it? Meaning:

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i != 2 && i != 3) {
    // do whatever needs to be done
  }
}
```

achieves the **exact** same thing; without introducing implicit "goto" logic. Why manipulating the control flow this way - without a need?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 2)
        i += 2;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

But I agree with others that it is a bad idea to change a loop variable like this.